# JavaScript double parenthesis in angularJs input directive's source code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

In the angularJs source code there's syntax I've never seen before. Can someone explain whats going on between the logical operator's parenthesis and the dependency filled parenthesis in "(inputType[lowercase(attr.type)] || inputType.text)(scope, element, attr, ctrls[0], $sniffer, $browser, $filter, $parse);"?

its context:

```
var inputDirective = ['$browser', '$sniffer', '$filter', '$parse',
    function($browser, $sniffer, $filter, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['?ngModel'],
    link: {
      pre: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        if (ctrls[0]) {
          (inputType[lowercase(attr.type)] || inputType.text)(scope, element, attr, ctrls[0], $sniffer, $browser, $filter, $parse);
        }
      }
    }
  };
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a regular function call, but the function that gets called is determined by the first part:

```
(inputType[lowercase(attr.type)] || inputType.text)
```

It is easier to follow in a smaller example:

```
var functionToCall = ...;
var obj = {
  goodbye: function(name) { alert('Goodbye ' + name); } 
  hello: function(name) { alert('Hello ' + name); }
};
(obj[functionToCall] || obj.hello)(name);
```

If `functionToCall == 'goodbye'`, this calls `obj.goodbye(name)`; if `functionToCall == 'hello'`, it calls `obj.hello(name)`. But if `functionToCall` is anything else, it defaults to `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will understand it better like this:

```
var func = inputType[lowercase(attr.type)];
if(!func) func = inputType.text;
func(scope, element, attr, ctrls[0], $sniffer, $browser, $filter, $parse);
```

`||` is the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR). `expr1 || expr2` returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means `inputType[lowercase(attr.type)]` and `inputType.text` is a function. Second parantheses contain the parameters.

Consider this simplified `inputType` implementation.

```
var inputType = {
    text : function(scope, element, attr, ctrls, sniffer, browser, filter, parse){
        //do stuff
    },
    button : function(scope, element, attr, ctrls, sniffer, browser, filter, parse){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

When `attr.type` returns something other than text or button, it defaults to text function and calls it with the given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with where in the angular source this is, so I don't know where `inputType` is, but it must be an object which has a number of functions for different input types, and its "default" one is `text`.

This code:

```
(inputType[lowercase(attr.type)] || inputType.text)
```

makes use of the `||` (logical or) operator. The operator takes two operands and returns the first (left) one if the operand is `true`. If the left operand is evaluates to `false` (or, importantly, `undefined`), then it returns the second (right) operand.

So what this does is it looks up `attr.type` in the `inputType` object. If it finds it there, it returns that function; if not, it returns the function that is assigned to `inputType.text`. The next set of parenthesis is the argument list passed to this resulting function.

Using the `||` in this way is a really convenient way to set default or fallback values to incoming arguments. Another shorthand solution you might have seen is the ternary operator:

```
var func = inputType[lowercase(attr.type)] ? inputType[lowercase(attr.type)] : inputType.text;
func( scope, element, attr, ... );
```

I think the `||` version is a little more slick here, as it will always be when the value you're checking for is simply true/false.